# How to customer group header of List component in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a list component with config grouped is true. The list items grouped by grouper defined in the store. Now I want to set custom template for each group header. For example, to show number of items in each group on the header.
Is there any way to do that in Sencha Touch 2, or any extend component that help me archive that.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [getGroupString](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getGroupString) on the associated data store. From within that method you can access the record and store (via *this*).